# State of a signaled thread in Java when calling condition.signal()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, thread-synchronization

I am looking for the answer to the following question. Suppose we have two threads in Java. We synchronize them by using Lock and Condition classes on the same object of Lock:

1. Thread A calls: condition.await();
2. Thread B does some work and then calls: condition.signal();
3. Thread B does some post signal work and finally unlocks the lock.

What is the state and the behaviour of the Thread A, when it receives a signal from the Thread B, but Thread B has not yet unlocked the lock, so before obtaining that lock?

Comment: Thread B locks on the same object that Thread A before doing its work (so before point 2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why await of Condition releases the lock but signal does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058828/why-await-of-condition-releases-the-lock-but-signal-does-not)

Comment: So reading that post I have got the idea that once a thread is awaiting and has just been signalled, it must obtain the lock before returning from await(). Does this mean that the awaiting thread (Thread A) is still in the state "Running" but simply it has given up the lock (for the time being)?

Answer (score 0):

Without code i cannot tell you more, but lets try to explain.

If Thread B signal to Thread A before finishing his work (lets say in some method), to Thread A, and that thread starts with work (same method) Thread A will stop with work, because Thread B still hold "locked object".

Don't forget that thread A will stop with his work before locking object by Thread B.